# javax.xml.transform.Transformer input source size limit

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing

Does the Transformer (transform method) has a limit to the size for the input source?

I'm trying to transform a quite long (18M) XML and I get a strange error saying

```
"The element type "HR" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</HR>"."
```

but there is no such element in the input source...

I get the IS this way:

```
HttpResponse hrep = hclient.execute( get );
InputStream istr = hrep.getEntity().getContent();
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource( istr );
...
```

If I "cut down" the the input source, than it works...

Or maybe do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, javax.xml.transform.Transformer is an interface, not an implementation, and any limits are likely to vary with the implementation.

Secondly, this error message gives no suggestion that a limit has been exceeded. Rather, it suggests strongly that your input "XML" is not well-formed.

Comment: the "HR" tag strongly suggests html input, _not_ xml (although it _could_ be xhtml).

Comment: The XML is a result of an http request and after saving this response in a file, I noticed it was not was I expected. In fact it was an 505 Error (and it isn't well formed...). Therefore the above error message.